# Failed To set Proxy: Wrong parameter libgit2sharp

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

I'm having some problems when I try to clone a repository using the library libgit2sharp.

I'm getting this error:

```
A first chance exception of type 'LibGit2Sharp.LibGit2SharpException' occurred in LibGit2Sharp.dll 
Additional information: Failed to set proxy: Wrong parameter.
```

I'm trying to clone like this:

```
var gitServerUri = new Uri(Settings.Default.GitServerUrl);
var cred = Git.Credentials.Get(gitServerUri.Host);

string clonedRepoPath = Repository.Clone(project.GitUrl(),projectLocalPath, new CloneOptions()
        {
            CredentialsProvider = (_url, _user, _cred) => new UsernamePasswordCredentials
            {
                Username = cred.Login,
                Password = cred.Password,
            }
        });
```

I tried to find in wiki of libgit2sharp where i should put the proxy config, but i didn't found.

I will be grateful if someone can help.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding proxy handling, libgit2 and thus LibGit2Sharp behave a lot like the way git itself handles proxy settings.

Those can be defined in the git configuration stores (local, global, system, ...) with the following entry names...

- `remote.<remote_name>.proxy`
- `http.proxy`

...or set through the environment `HTTPS_PROXY` or `HTTP_PROXY` variables.

You can get a better insight about the probing strategy in the actual libgit2 **[code](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/a7fa970f8b216b79a5d237a9d87ac88e2371ae46/src/remote.c#L753-L810)**.

For more detailed information, see the following relevant issues about this topic:

- **[Proposal to leverage Windows Proxy Auto Discovery](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/2589)**
- **[Using a proxy url with credentials](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2106)**