# Git network operations behind corporate firewall using LibGit2Sharp throws

Tags: proxy, ntlm, git-push, libgit2sharp

I am trying to use LibGit2Sharp to `git push origin` using the following

```
using(var repo = new Repository("path\to\repo\.git"))
{
   var commit = repo.Commit("Commit message", author, committer);

   var options = new PushOptions{ CredentialsProvider = (u, s, t) => new UserNamePasswordCredentials { Username = "username", Password = "password" } };
   repo.Network.Push(repo.Branches("master"), options); 
}
```

I get a LibGit2SharpException saying

> *Additional information: Failed to set proxy: The parameter is incorrect.*

But in git bash everything is fine when I do `git push origin`.

We have NTLM proxy at work, and I am pushing to an intranet https remote URI. I have configured the proxy as `http://username:password@proxy.fqdn:80` in the following:

- Env vars: HTTP_PROXY & HTTPS_PROXY
- repos .git/config:

  - remote.origin.proxy
  - http.proxy
  - https.proxy
  - http.sslCAInfo & https.sslCAInfo - this is the path to the root CA for the host

Having read through [this SO and links there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28811640/269452) it seems like libgit2sharp should find the proxy parameter just fine. Has anyone gotten this to work behing ntlm?

I am using:
Windows 7, LibGit2Sharp.0.22.0, Git 2.10.1.windows.1, bash 4.3.46, .net4.5.2

Any ideas/tricks on achieving the push through an alternative are greatly welcome too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from "[`libgit2 src/transports/winhttp.c`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/89c332e41b12a72d89de40d63bc568c56a2c336a/src/transports/winhttp.c#L443-L449)", which calls directly the Windows API [`WinHttpSetOption` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384114(v=vs.85).aspx).

It passes an [`WINHTTP_OPTION_PROXY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384066(v=vs.85).aspx#WINHTTP_OPTION_PROXY) to set or retrieves an [`WINHTTP_PROXY_INFO`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383912(v=vs.85).aspx) structure that contains the proxy data on an existing session handle or request handle.

That function returns `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` (A parameter is not valid) only if `WINHTTP_OPTION_WEB_SOCKET_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL` is set to a value lower than `15000`.

I don't know why [LibGit2Sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp) has that issue but try first only set the environment variables `HTTP_PROXY` & `HTTPS_PROXY` (not `http.proxy` & `https.proxy`), and make sure to use the same http url for both proxy environment variables (not https url for `HTTPS_PROXY`)

The official libgit2 bug on this is [issue 2106](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/2106), which is supposed to be resolved with [PR 3110](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3110), and [commit 1dc4491](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/1dc449105b329ea4f8ea9982bc2da869d231c04a).
However, that fix is *not* part of a release yet.

Comment: @aateeque do you have any special character in your username or password for the proxy?

Comment: Nope, nothing. Just letters & numbers

Comment: @aateeque I ahve edited the answer with a reference to a fix (which is yet to be delivered)

Comment: @aateeque technically, it should be possible to take libgit2 master source code (which includes the fix: https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/commit/1dc449105b329ea4f8ea9982bc2da869d231c04a), and recompile it, and then rebuild LibGitSharp based on that newly compiled library: that would at least test if the issue is resolved with that very latest libgit2.

Comment: spot on! Just tried with 0.23.0-pre20160922233542 and it works! Thanks!